# How to test container class?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have a class `ListContainer`.
The class a container for a list and allow 3 operations:

1. add
2. remove
3. getNotValid (return list of not valid elements).

The list is private in the class, so i cannot check that add really add element.
How do you think I should test the add functionality?

for my opinion I should check it by the getNotValid.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
Container::Container() {
}


void Container::add(Element element) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    list.push_back(element);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void Container::remove(unsigned int elementId) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    list<Element>::iterator it;
    for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
        if (element->id == elementId) { //TODO is it the real check
            list.erase(it);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

list<Element> Container::getNotValid() {
    list<Element> result;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    list<Element>::iterator it;
    for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it) {
        if (element->isNotValid()) {
            result.push_back(*it);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is anything being done with "valid" items in the list or is the list purely used to return invalid items?

Comment: getNotValid remove and return the not valid element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes are typically tested through either their public interface or (using an integration test) by testing the effect a certain operation will have on some application state.

If the private list does nothing more than allow the user of the API to retrieve invalid items, then I would say you only need to test the list using the `add`, `remove` and `getNotValid` methods.

If valid items are used in some way (like being written to a file system or database, for instance) then you should test the class through an integration test and make sure that the desired effect on the application state is indeed taking place.

Comment: I think like you that we should try to do the best to test through the public API, so in this case the test will be to add not valid element , remove , and that check that getnot valid return nothing. additional test will be done base on the public api.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write a class that you can't test. In your case, the class doesn't have any public API to test it. This means you can't write any serious tests besides checking that you can call the three methods and they don't throw exceptions.

On the other hand, you shouldn't add methods just to make a class testable. Note the **should not** - it's not **must not**. If you take testing serious, it's more important to have enough useful tests than keeping the API simple.

In your case, it would make sense to add a `size()` method - when you add/remove elements, the size of the list should change.

Or add a `toString()` method. This would be useful when debugging and to write tests:

```
ListContainer c = new ListContainer();
c.add("x");
assertEquals("[x]", c.toString());
```

Comment: Just be a bit careful because people like to change `toString()` and this will break the test(s).

Answer (score 0):

Testing private things are never necessary. There must be some measurable effect of adding to and removing from that list. Testing the class that contains the `ListContainer` should tell you if the `ListContainer` is working properly.

Maybe you could add some extra code so that it is easier to comment on?

Answer (score 0):

How is `add` operation visible to `ListContainer` clients? Assume I use your class, add an item.. and then what? How do I use it in this state? Can I observe any behavior change? State change? Added item's properties change? I should be able to *observe some changes*, and this is what you should focus on when testing. *Observable changes*.

<sub>Alternatively, you can expose `private` lists for unit tests (by changing their visiblity in regard of test classes/assemblies).</sub>